# JAVA "JDBC:The result set is closed" error at end of first pass through while loop

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, while-loop

So I've made some changes to my script and now I send all the details to separate threads to do all the work, however I still get the same error when I get to the end of the first iteration.  Now I'm really at a loss...!

```
while (results.next()){
    try{
        webDriverCapabilities mywebDriver = new webDriverCapabilities();    
        String browserType = results.getString("browser").toString();
        String Env =  results.getString("Env").toString();
        String scenarioID = results.getString("test_scenario_id").toString();
        String test_description = results.getString("description").toString();
        String test_exec_id = results.getString("test_exec_queue_id").toString();
        String system = results.getString("system").toString();
        String subsystem = results.getString("subsystem").toString();
        String testRelease = results.getString("release").toString();

        DesiredCapabilities capability = mywebDriver.browserEnvType(browserType, Env)                       

        //Check that there is a node that matches requirements.
        String getNodeAvailabilityString = constants.getNodeAvailability(Env, browserType);
        ResultSet nodesAvailable = stmt.executeQuery(getNodeAvailabilityString);
        String nodeID = null;
            try {
                nodesAvailable.absolute(1);
                nodeID = nodesAvailable.getString(1).toString();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {}
                        //If a node is returned then mark it as in use then kick off a new thread
            if(nodeID !=null){
                System.out.println("Test Found");

                Runnable subThread = new individualThreadSession(browserType, scenarioID, Env, test_description, test_exec_id, system, subsystem, testRelease, nodeID);
                new Thread(subThread).start();                  

                //Wait 2 seconds before proceeding to give the thread chance to spin up and reserve nodes etc 
                newAction.simpleWait(2);
                        }
            } catch (SQLException e){}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are possibly creating two connections, maybe this is the problem. Try removing the second `con = DriverManager.getConnection(MAIN.DBConnectionString);`

Comment: Not only that; be aware that you are not returning a single resource to the database in the entire program (connections, statements, result sets...)  This can lead to performance problems, and even resources shortage, in your database.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that thanks, unfortunately the problem still exists...

Comment: @Jorge_B Currently not a big issue but it is on my list of cleanup activities to deal with once I've got the main elements working (like the empty catch blocks etc that were mentioned below).

Comment: Have you considered implementing [Connection Pooling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/jdbc_connection_pools.html)?
That will help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by the time your new Thread(s) start working,
the `results` result set is already at its end as your
loop in the current thread is done.
It is a weird use case to pass a result set to a thread like you do.
You should redesign this in my opinion depending on what you need.
A side note: don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: Previously I was only returning one result and then passing that across to a new thread which had the drawback that it would pick up all entries one at a time and dump them all onto one node if it was available so if the node went down all those queued threads would also fail...  I guess I need to somehow get my result set of 1-100 and for each line create some kind of sub set of results and pass that across to a thread, but how do I solve this current issue..?